# Is there a NuGet package or Built in method to convert a string into another meaningful string or Dummy data using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert a set of string into another meaningful string using c#
For Example

[image]

I want to convert the string "Aneesh" into "Syam"(**The Name should Always convert into same Dummy name Always**)

**The Dummy values should be consistent based on an input seed**

Comment: Are you supplying the list of dummy names ?

Comment: `var dummyNames = names.Select(x => x.GetHashCode().ToString());`

Comment: No, I don't have, Is there any Library that I can use for to supply Dummy data?

Comment: Did you even try anything? Are you stuck on **mapping** one string to another, or on **finding a random representation**?

Comment: Why do you want `Syam` **specifically**? Why not `Gerald` or `cromulent` or `12JH811!`?

Comment: @mjwills  No, it can be any meaningful name. But it should always produce consistent output based on the same input.
Suppose for **Aneesh** we get **Gerald**, It should always generate **Gerald** for **Aneesh**

Comment: @MichaelRandall I don't think `GetHashCode` is guaranteed to be consistent. https://andrewlock.net/why-is-string-gethashcode-different-each-time-i-run-my-program-in-net-core/

Comment: OK, but it needs to be a name? From what language / culture? Can two different inputs generate the same output (i.e. would it be valid if Aneesh became Gerald, but Bobby also became Gerald)?

Comment: so requirements are a bit vague. is it required to be 1to1, is it also required to be reversible (i guess OP means this). Do the outputs need to be meaningful?

Comment: @mjwills Actually I want this to Mask the data with Dummy, It can be irrespective of culture/Language. Also, it's not valid same Gerald is repeating for both Aneesh and Bobby( should be 1 to 1)

Comment: OK, the short answer is "this is very hard". Since given the sample size of the input is virtually limitless (since there are lots of different names in the world) you need a virtually limitless output data set and mapping system. I'd consider rethinking your problem to avoid needing meaningful names (since if you can avoid that then generating a numeric hash with low collision likelihood becomes a possibility).

Comment: @mjwills i should have read your comment, oops

Comment: Would `12JH811!` be a valid name?

Comment: Indeed, "encode as UTF-8, encrypt, then encode the result in some reversible ASCII format that satisfies the requirement of being a valid name" would be an answer here, but then we'd need to know the requirement for a valid name.

Answer (score 1):

The Random Class of C# uses Seeds, if u would for example when you want to convert Aneesh you would put Aneesh as the input seed (just convert it into int with a method you like or set a reference int to it) and the Random Class if im not wrong should always do the same randoms then. Just convert those via int -> char -> string and you got your random word.

another way of doing it obviously would be setting up a consistent pair of strings, and just when converting taking the other one.

But i dont understand what you mean Aneesh into Syam, because u first said you want another meaningfull string which is consistent, and in the other hand you want string a swapped with string b, these are different things and can be acomplished in diff. ways

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution that comes to my mind is to add 1 on every character:

```
var result = input.ToDictionary(x => x, x => new string(x.Select(y => y + 1).ToArray());
```

This produces different values for different keys, but is highly deterministic and unabmigious.

```
[
    ["Aneesh", "Boffti"],
    ["Head", "Ifbe"],
    ["Hand", "Iboe"]
]
```

Maybe you also need some check that character do not "overflow", that is `z + 1` results in `{`, but instead of `A`.

If you need a bit more randomness you can of course add any different number than `1` and add that to every character.

Another appraoch which is not de-anonymizable as it produces compeleteley unrelated data is to just randomize based on the index within your input-list:

```
var result = input.Select((x, i) => $"Dummy{ i }");
```

Comment: The downside of this is that it isn't a very good mask (i.e. easy to de-anonymise). Plus it will generate lots of data that isn't a "valid" name.

Comment: @mjwills I read "culture-irrelevant" as "does not even have to be a name at all", but also just some random trunc. Of course its easy to de-anonymise, but I don´t see why it should based upon  the question. It´s just "dummy".

Comment: I mention it since I _suspect_ the underlying problem (although the OP isn't 100% explicit, granted) is some form of anonymization / GDPR related. (Plus the use of the `meaningful name` terminology).